# Installing android studio

Tags: android, qt

When I tried to install android studio on my 14.04 LTS Ubuntu system on `opt` directory as according to mentioned on by clayton (Ubuntu user) but I could not install it as accordingly.

1. Unpack android studio zip on download directory
2. Then open terminal fetch the file through `cd ~/Downloads`
3. Then I enter `sudo -i`
4. After then I tried to move android studio to opt directory `mv android-studio /opt`
   Then it says:

> mv: cannot stat ‘android-studio’: No such file or directory

And I installed `Qt creator5.3.2` on `/opt` directory for third party installation policy.It works fine except I could not fetch the examples on `Qt creator` and it is not showing the version of `Qt`.

If anybody could help me how to solve this problem. I would be really thankful in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu make :

#### Installing Ubuntu Make :

**For Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

**For Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10 :**

Ubuntu make is already in the official repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

---

#### Installing Android Studio :

```
umake android
```

#### Uninstall Android Studio :

```
umake android --remove
```

Comment: I do the same but when I enter "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
" command I saw this error :
Setting up android-studio (4.12.0-ubuntu0) ...
unzip:  cannot find or open /opt/android-studio-ide-*, /opt/android-studio-ide-*.zip or /opt/android-studio-ide-*.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/android-studio-ide-*’: No such file or directory
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
find: `/opt/android-studio/': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package android-studio (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status1

Comment: Please post a new question for your problem.